# Repeatable Data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a Laravel app but come from a WordPress background. In WordPress, it's reasonably straight forward to create custom fields that are repeatable e.g. I have a field called "Task" that can be repeated X number of times and it will be stored on the database.

Is there a best practice way of doing this in Laravel?

I understand that Javascript can be used to create repeatable form fields, and I could store that data as JSON in a MySQL database (using the latest versions of MySQL), but I'd also like this repeatable data to hold relationships e.g. relate a task to a day of the week (stored in another table).

Any advice or thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Put any code about this please ? some table data or fields ? to know more about your problem :)

Comment: It's more theoretical at the moment - essentially I'm looking for an example or best practice. I'll make a diagram later to demonstrate the problem better.